# Can I reference ResourceResolver?

Tags: servlet-filters, apache-felix, sling

I have this `Filter`:

```
@SlingFilter(description="", vendor="", order=10) 
class MyFilter extends DoNothingFilter {
  @Reference private ResourceResolver;
}
```

When I am building with this `@Reference` line my bundle is not containing attached filter (otherwise it's here). What is wrong with this and how to avoid it? Logs say nothing about any issue related to this bundle update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the resource resolver is not an OSGi service and so it cannot be referenced like that.

you either get it from a sling http request or create a new one using the resource resolver factory (which is an OSGi service)